Combines Angular Material table-expandable-rows and table-wrapped, and adds custom expand details but cannot show the custom detail content
I tried to create a component that combines table-expandable-row and table-wrapped, and use ngTemplateOutletContext to add custom details, but it does not work.
Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-table-expandable-rows-with-table-wrapper
How can I fix it?

When I changed ContentChild to
  @ContentChild('temp', {
    read: TemplateRef,
  })
  template: TemplateRef<any>;

It started working, so we need to be specific with the selector. Also promote the ng-template to the top of the content children in HTML.
Full Code:
Table Example HTML:
<app-table-expandable-rows
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  [columns]="displayedColumns"
  matSort
  #sort="matSort"
>
  <!-- Custom Detail -->
  <ng-template let-data #temp>
    <div>{{ data | json }}</div>
  </ng-template>
  <!-- Custom column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Custom column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Custom column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Custom column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
  </ng-container>
</app-table-expandable-rows>

Table Example HTML:
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableModule, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort, MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { TableExpandableRowsComponent } from '../table-expandable-rows/table-expandable-rows.component';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  description: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {
    position: 1,
    name: 'Hydrogen',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H',
    description: `Hydrogen is a chemical element with symbol H and atomic number 1. With a standard
        atomic weight of 1.008, hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table.`,
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    name: 'Helium',
    weight: 4.0026,
    symbol: 'He',
    description: `Helium is a chemical element with symbol He and atomic number 2. It is a
        colorless, odorless, tasteless, non-toxic, inert, monatomic gas, the first in the noble gas
        group in the periodic table. Its boiling point is the lowest among all the elements.`,
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    name: 'Lithium',
    weight: 6.941,
    symbol: 'Li',
    description: `Lithium is a chemical element with symbol Li and atomic number 3. It is a soft,
        silvery-white alkali metal. Under standard conditions, it is the lightest metal and the
        lightest solid element.`,
  },
  {
    position: 4,
    name: 'Beryllium',
    weight: 9.0122,
    symbol: 'Be',
    description: `Beryllium is a chemical element with symbol Be and atomic number 4. It is a
        relatively rare element in the universe, usually occurring as a product of the spallation of
        larger atomic nuclei that have collided with cosmic rays.`,
  },
  {
    position: 5,
    name: 'Boron',
    weight: 10.811,
    symbol: 'B',
    description: `Boron is a chemical element with symbol B and atomic number 5. Produced entirely
        by cosmic ray spallation and supernovae and not by stellar nucleosynthesis, it is a
        low-abundance element in the Solar system and in the Earth's crust.`,
  },
  {
    position: 6,
    name: 'Carbon',
    weight: 12.0107,
    symbol: 'C',
    description: `Carbon is a chemical element with symbol C and atomic number 6. It is nonmetallic
        and tetravalent—making four electrons available to form covalent chemical bonds. It belongs
        to group 14 of the periodic table.`,
  },
  {
    position: 7,
    name: 'Nitrogen',
    weight: 14.0067,
    symbol: 'N',
    description: `Nitrogen is a chemical element with symbol N and atomic number 7. It was first
        discovered and isolated by Scottish physician Daniel Rutherford in 1772.`,
  },
  {
    position: 8,
    name: 'Oxygen',
    weight: 15.9994,
    symbol: 'O',
    description: `Oxygen is a chemical element with symbol O and atomic number 8. It is a member of
         the chalcogen group on the periodic table, a highly reactive nonmetal, and an oxidizing
         agent that readily forms oxides with most elements as well as with other compounds.`,
  },
  {
    position: 9,
    name: 'Fluorine',
    weight: 18.9984,
    symbol: 'F',
    description: `Fluorine is a chemical element with symbol F and atomic number 9. It is the
        lightest halogen and exists as a highly toxic pale yellow diatomic gas at standard
        conditions.`,
  },
  {
    position: 10,
    name: 'Neon',
    weight: 20.1797,
    symbol: 'Ne',
    description: `Neon is a chemical element with symbol Ne and atomic number 10. It is a noble gas.
        Neon is a colorless, odorless, inert monatomic gas under standard conditions, with about
        two-thirds the density of air.`,
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-example',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    TableExpandableRowsComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: './table-example.component.html',
  styleUrl: './table-example.component.css',
})
export class TableExampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  elementData = ELEMENT_DATA;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild('sort') sort: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}

Table Expandable Rows TS:
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Component,
  ContentChildren,
  ContentChild,
  ViewChild,
  Input,
  AfterContentInit,
  QueryList,
  effect,
  input,
  computed,
  TemplateRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatColumnDef,
  MatHeaderRowDef,
  MatNoDataRow,
  MatRowDef,
  MatTable,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTableDataSource,
} from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import {
  animate,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-expandable-rows',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatTableModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule],
  templateUrl: './table-expandable-rows.component.html',
  styleUrl: './table-expandable-rows.component.scss',
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed,void', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
      transition(
        'expanded <=> collapsed',
        animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')
      ),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class TableExpandableRowsComponent<T> implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(MatHeaderRowDef) headerRowDefs: QueryList<MatHeaderRowDef>;
  @ContentChildren(MatRowDef) rowDefs: QueryList<MatRowDef<T>>;
  @ContentChildren(MatColumnDef) columnDefs: QueryList<MatColumnDef>;
  @ContentChild(MatNoDataRow) noDataRow: MatNoDataRow;
  @ContentChild('temp')
  template: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ViewChild(MatTable, { static: true }) table: MatTable<T>;

  @Input() dataSource: DataSource<T>;
  columns = input<string[]>([]);

  expandedElement: any;

  columnsToDisplayWithExpand = computed<string[]>(() => {
    return [...this.columns(), 'expand'];
  });

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.columnDefs.forEach((columnDef) => this.table.addColumnDef(columnDef));
    this.rowDefs.forEach((rowDef) => this.table.addRowDef(rowDef));
    this.headerRowDefs.forEach((headerRowDef) =>
      this.table.addHeaderRowDef(headerRowDef)
    );
    this.table.setNoDataRow(this.noDataRow);
  }
}

Table Expandable Rows HTML:
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  multiTemplateDataRows
  class="mat-elevation-z8"
>
  <ng-content></ng-content>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="expand">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef aria-label="row actions">&nbsp;</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        aria-label="expand row"
        (click)="
          expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element;
          $event.stopPropagation()
        "
      >
        @if (expandedElement === element) {
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
        } @else {
        <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        }
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let element"
      [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplayWithExpand().length"
    >
      <div
        class="example-element-detail"
        [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
      >
        <!-- <div class="example-element-diagram">
          <div class="example-element-position">{{ element.position }}</div>
          <div class="example-element-symbol">{{ element.symbol }}</div>
          <div class="example-element-name">{{ element.name }}</div>
          <div class="example-element-weight">{{ element.weight }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="example-element-description">
          {{ element.description }}
          <span class="example-element-description-attribution">
            -- Wikipedia8
          </span>
        </div> -->
        <ng-template
          [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
          [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: element }"
        >
        </ng-template>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplayWithExpand()"></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplayWithExpand()"
    class="example-element-row"
    [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
    (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"
  ></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']"
    class="example-detail-row"
  ></tr>

  <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Stackblitz Demo
